# Swap characters in sequence randomly (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, sequence, swap

I have an input value is a set of sequences as follows:

```
{ 'ABCDE'
  'ABCD'
  'ABE'
  'ABCDE'
  'ABD'
  'ABCD'
  'ABCDE' }
```

I try to swap 'A' and 'B' in 3 random sequences and keep other sequences no changes. Could anyone have any suggestion ?

Comment: You should specify if by 'A' and 'B' you mean always the _first two chars_ of the selected string, or _any_ occurrences of 'A'  and 'B' (possibly not the first two chars? Possibly repeated in the same string?)

Comment: thanks ! I mean 'A' and 'B' not always the first two chars . There are some strings which may have 'A' and 'B' inside, and in that case, we will not swap the first 2 chars in those kinds of strings. Please tell me what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution

```
A={ 'ABCDE'
  'ABCD'
  'ABE'
  'ABCDE'
  'ABD'
  'ABCD'
  'ABCDE' };

N = numel(A);

for r = randperm(N,3)
    A(r) = A{r}([2 1 3:end]);
end
```

or

```
for r = randperm(N,3)
    A{r}(1:2) = A{r}([2 1]);
end
```

`randperm(N,3)` selects 3 random values from `1:N`

then with indexing `[2 1 3:end]` we can swap first and second elements

Comment: thanks ! I mean 'A' and 'B' not always the first two chars . There are some strings which may have 'A' and 'B' inside, and in that case, we will not swap the first 2 chars in those kinds of strings. Please tell me what should I do ?

Comment: @kgk Are A and B  ordered? What if we have repeated A and B?  It is useful to provide a general example that cover all conditions and provide the expected output.

Comment: yes, A and B ordered as A is always in front of B. I will ask another question with the expected output .

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to have a `for loop` but instead have an extra data conversion step from `cell` to `char` and then from `char` back to `cell`, this would solve your problem:

```
N = numel(A);
r = randperm(N,3);
A = char(A);
A(r,[1,2]) = A(r,[2,1]);
A = cellstr(A);
```

Comment: thanks ! I mean 'A' and 'B' not always the first two chars . There are some strings which may have 'A' and 'B' inside, and in that case, we will not swap the first 2 chars in those kinds of strings. Please tell me what should I do ?